# What set do these stickers belong to?

Tags: set-identification, sticker-identification

I have searched for these stickers in several places but I can't seem to find what sets they go to.

[image]

Comment: Is the bottom one a sticker or print?

Comment: I didn't find anything for the 1x2 brick on Bricklink in "Bricks, Decorated" category or the tile in "Tile, Decorated"; I'm pretty sure LEGO doesn't do stickers spanning on multiple parts any longer so that one might be a bit old. Could be not-LEGO, too.

Comment: A recent set with lots of stickers spanning multiple parts is [set 10241](http://brickset.com/sets/10241-1/maersk-line-triple-e). Are these mystery bricks LEGO or some other clone brand? Check the pieces for LEGO identification numbers and LEGO imprint on studs.

Answer (score 5):

For the top item, I have found this to come from set 6338 Hurricane Harbor. Here is a photo of the sticker sheet that came with this set:
[image]

As for the bottom, please see comment to the question.